# Check Android Emulator state

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.3

I created my android virtual device using command as folow:

```
android create avd --target 1 --name emu --abi x86
```

then I tried to run emulator:

```
emulator -avd emu &
```

during the emulator starting I was trying to make command as follow:

```
adb shell
```

but I had an error:

```
error: device offline
```

and when i made command:

```
echo $?
```

I had output "1" until emulator get started. 
Is it any possibility to check current emulator state using the terminal command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use another terminal window and type adb logcat commnad.